# Using Ubuntu Emacs init file on Windows; possible multiple issues

Tags: org-mode, init-file, microsoft-windows

I've seen [Manage same init file for Linux and Windows](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/manage-same-init-file-for-linux-and-windows), but it is not quite what I want. Bear with the description of issues and my attempts for resolution.

I recently installed Emacs on Windows using `emacs-25.3_1-x86_64.zip` from the gnu ftp server, and did not install any other file. I found the init file `.emacs`, and the diretory `.emacs.d` in `C:\Users\MyUSer\AppData\Roaming\` -- as the docs indicated. I copied my `.emacs` for emacs25.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 and the accompanying `.dotemacs.org` and pasted them in `Roaming`. I also pasted the `org-dotemacs.el` in `Romaming\.emacs.d\`. The contents of my init file are as follows:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (wheatgrass)))
 '(initial-frame-alist (quote ((fullscreen . maximized))))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (pdf-tools org-dotemacs))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))

(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)

;;;;org-mode configuration
;; Enable org-mode
(require 'org)

;;org-dotemacs
(require 'org-dotemacs)
(load-file "C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/org-dotemacs.el")
(org-dotemacs-load-default)
```

The message I get is: `Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, org-dotemacs`. So I decided to look into the list of packages. Here I have another perplexing behaviour. The list loads, but I get errors contacting to org archive; output given below because I don't know if it is relevant to the problem mentioned ahead:

```
gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) GnuTLS library not found
Opening TLS connection to `orgmode.org'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --x509cafile nil -p 443 orgmode.org'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --x509cafile nil -p 443 orgmode.org --protocols ssl3'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `openssl s_client -connect orgmode.org:443 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof'...failed
Opening TLS connection to `orgmode.org'...failed
Package refresh done
Failed to download `org' archive.
You can run the command `package-list-packages' with M-x pa-l- RET
Failed to download `org' archive.
Contacting host: melpa.org:80
```

Within the list of packages I find many with the label `incompatible` which is where I find `org-dotemacs` and on clicking it:

```
Status: Incompatible because it depends on uninstallable packages.
Archive: melpa

Version: 20151119.1022
Summary: Store your emacs config as an org file, and choose which bits to load.
Requires: org-7.9.3 (not available), cl-lib-1.0
Homepage: https://github.com/vapniks/org-dotemacs
```

The problem is in the **Status** and **Requires** fields, because I have org-mode, in fact `M-x org-version` gives `Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ c:/Users/MyUser/Downloads/emacs-25.3_1-x86_64/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/org/)`. I assumed something that needs `org-7.9.3` would work with `org-8.2.10`.

What is wrong? Did I miss downloading some files from the gnu ftp server? Do I need to install some other software alongside for emacs to run properly on Windows? I can program but I am not a professional, I have somehow managed to use emacs on Ubuntu. I don't even understand how to run emacs with the `--debug-init` option on Windows.

Comment: Maybe, that answer resolves all your problems: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27251/2370 Because of the TLS-problem you are currently working with GNU Emacs' own version of org which is known to be very outdated.

Comment: @Tobias I tried doing what you suggested. The files at that link are only available for emacs26 pretest but i nevertheless downloaded the one marked `deps` but it did not work -- I don't see the updated org in my package list. May be I should just delete the emacs25 installation and reinstallemacs26 with deps.